# Manage transactional emails from the backend?

Tags: transactional-mail, order-email, queue, ee-1.14.2.2

Since Magento 1.9, all transactional emails were being queue and sent with cronjob. That is really good, but what I am concern here is about is there anyway to manage them.

How and where Magento save them? I think core_email_queue serve for this one.

I tried to find which part/modules in Magento core handle this job (queueing email and setup cronjob to send). But unfortunately, I can't.

Long-live bloody poor Magento documentation!

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank.

Answer (score -1):

You could manage transactional emails in the backend on *system/transactional emails*

There you could manage your emails, add new or what ever you want.

If you are looking for the code, you could see the emails on code/mage/sales/model for orders or goes to /core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Email/

Comment: I want to manage the transactional **emails** not **email templates**, could you know how many transactional emails was created, sent or the current status of that email?

Comment: Oh sorry, as far as i know, there is no way to get this, but you could implement this easy.

Create a new table with specific columns like , sender , date , etc...

Then goes to the triggers that send the emails, and when it send the email, update to the table with the data of the email.

Then if you want, you could create a module to display the data or to manage with a few actions on the adminhtml, but as far as i know, there is no way to check what u want.